# Receive data from Arduino serial port then place it on text box the data came from rfid tag

Tags: vb.net, textbox, arduino-uno

Good day, my project is vb.net using rfid which is MFRC522, my reader is arduino, I connected and receive data from serial successfully, but my problem is in every time I tap the id the pin of id will stack on the text box,and continuously add, I want that in every time that I tap the id the pin change or update,

This is my code

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
    studtag.Text &= receivedData
    time.Text = Now
    timein.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
End Sub

Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    Dim Incoming As String
    Try
        Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
        If Incoming Is Nothing Then
            Return "nothing" & vbCrLf
        Else
            Return Incoming
        End If
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    End Try
End Function
```

advance Thank you..

all replies are really much appreciated. I'm using VB.net 2010

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The line studtag.Text &= receivedData will do exactly what you describe. Remove the '&'

Comment: Thank you..I already try that but when i scan the card the data pop up but after 1 second it vanished..I just want to happen when i scan the another next card the data from the new card scanned replace the previous one..Thank you @peterG